# How to find the smallest number with just 0 and 7 which is divided by a given number?

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

This is one of algorithmic problem I encountered in one of interview. Unable to figure out how to solve it in most efficient way.

Comment: How would you create a list of all numbers consisting only of the digits 0 and 7 starting with the smallest, and then the second smallest etc.  It would probably start with [7, 70, 77, 700, 707...]

Comment: [Looks like this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16458026/1679537).

Comment: Plot twist: Wouldn't the result always be zero ? 
(you should mention 'the smallest number except 0')

Answer (score 2):

Here is my suggested code. It finds the smallest number with 0 and 7 (except the number 0) within the `long` range.
In this case, I'm looking for the result for 11.

```
public class Class007
{
   static long NUM = 11;
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       //NUM is the given number
       //find007() finds the smallest number with 0 & 7 that is divided by NUM
       System.out.print(find007(NUM));
   }

     static long find007(long n){

       if(is007(n))
         return n;

       if(n+NUM<n)
         return 0;

       return find007(n+NUM);
     }
     static boolean is007(long n){
        while(n!=0 && (n%10==0 || n%10==7))
         n=n/10;

       return n==0;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According by [THIS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16458026/how-to-find-the-smallest-number-with-just-0-and-1-which-is-divided-by-a-given-nu), in http://oeis.org/ you can find this class of number sequences: [Check your's here](http://oeis.org/A078246).

```
a(n) = min{A204094(k): k > 0 and A204094(k) mod n = 0}
```

Simply adapt the algorithm to fit your needs.