# Find smallest number formed by two digits divisible by given number

Tags: java, algorithm, math, division

I was asked the following question in an interview and I had no clue how to do it

> Write a program to find the smallest number that can be formed by 0
>   and 9 which is divisible by a given number.
>   For example, if given
>   number is 3 output should be 9,  if given number is 2 output is 90, 
>   if given number is 10 output is 90

I found this solution online but I haven't understood this one bit :-

```
public class Smallest0And9DivisibleNumber {
    public static int find(int divisible) {
        int bin = 1;
        while (true) {
            int res = translate(bin);
            if (res % divisible == 0) {
                return res;
            }
            bin += 1;
        }
    }

    private static int translate(int bin) {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = Integer.toBinaryString(bin).length(); i > 0; i--) {
            result *= result != 0 ? 10 : 0;
            int mask = 1 <<  (i - 1);
            result += (bin & mask) == mask ? 9 : 0;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        assert find(10) == 90;
        assert find(99) == 99;
        assert find(33) == 99;
        assert find(3) == 9;
        assert find(333) == 999;
        assert find(300) == 900;
        assert find(303) == 909;
        assert find(3033) == 9099;
        assert find(3303) == 9909;
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help with a good understanding or an alternative solution ?

Comment: It generates binary numbers 1, 10, 11, etc, replaces the 1 with 9, and tests for divisibility. That's all.

Comment: `System.out.println(find(299))` -> `500075407`

Comment: @TagirValeev Integer Overflow. Use `long` instead and you get `90090909909`

Comment: @tobias_k: exactly. However it's not specified in the question that it's allowed not to work for `299` (or many other numbers). You should always ask the interviewer for which input data the task should be solved. This may affect the solution pretty much.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29298656/how-to-find-the-smallest-number-with-just-0-and-7-which-is-divided-by-a-given-nu?lq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16458026/how-to-find-the-smallest-number-with-just-0-and-1-which-is-divided-by-a-given-nu?rq=1 Although people are posting brute force answers, there are faster algorithms by dynamic programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a similar approach.

How do we do it manually for 33:

```
Let's go from the least number which will be? - 0. Is it divisible? No.

Let's go up a number. 9. Is it divisible? No.

Again by a number 90. Is is divisible? No.

Again by a number 99. Is it divisible? Yes.
```

Let's look at the pattern.

```
0 9 90 99
```

How does it look like? binary! Yes, instead of a 1 we have 9.

Now i'll go from 0 till I get a number which divides it, in the form of a binary(by replacing 1 with 9).

we get

```
Number Binary    0 And 9
0        0         0
1        1         9
2        10        90
3        11        99
4        100       900
5        101       909
6        110       990
7        111       999
```

We get all the numbers which can be formed using 0 and 9 in an **ascending order**.

Comment: You are missing the part about the result being the *smallest* number that fulfills the conditions. The algorithm takes that into account by going *upwards* with the binary numbers and returning the first one, which gives you the smallest binary number. That is also valid for the *translated* numbers because the translation is a monotonous function.

Comment: @mastov well I think he is not missing that part !!

Comment: @Junaid: Sorry, I don't see it.

Comment: @mastov Perhaps because it wasn't there. I edited it in because as you point out it is an important point. I'm pretty sure Uma knows that just forgot to mention it.

Comment: It was obvious that numbers are generated in an ascending order, so I thought why to mention it. Thanks for the edit though @DanAllen

Comment: @DanAllen and UmaKanth: It is obvious for the binary numbers. It is not at all obvious (and still not there) why this ascending order is maintained when switching out numbers.

Comment: This is just a brute force search. There are much better algorithms.

Comment: @mastov 'Obvious' isn't a well defined term but I agree more could be done to show that the result is minimal.

Comment: @DanAllen: True, I can only speak for myself. In my case, I have to say that, even though I have some experience with that kind of thing, it would still cost me more than 5 lines to create a proof for the monotony of that translation function. So *I* don't call that obvious.

Comment: @mastov This includes a joke that has been around for 25 years to my knowledge: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151782/when-is-something-obvious .I think obvious means something the speaker knows to be so and can't be bothered to go into. If someone didn't understand the point that might be different. But if we all know it is so and are just debating whether it's obvious I don't think it's worth further work. If you want a proof I notice that you increment a binary by setting the lowest zero bit to 1 and clearing all the bits below it.

Comment: @DanAllen: But that might not be the case here. I'm afraid that most readers will just be convinced by the example, which is dangerous. About your proof sketch: Yes, that trick simplifies the proof a bit. But you would still transfer that operation to the 0/9-number in decimal and show that all the 9->0 transitions together have less weight than the one 0->9 transition, which would at least involve analyzing it as a finite geometric series.

Comment: Let's not make this post a mess. Let's stop it here. @mastov I suggest you to come up with an answer which could explain it more better. We all would be happy to learn.

Comment: Sorry for making the post a mess. I felt I needed to explain myself, since both you and Dan seemed to think about the simpler part of the "ascension" aspect, not about the monotony of the `translate` function. And I am also concerned about people believing things just because they seem to work in an example.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that the translate method is the one that needs more clarification.
Simply it is generating a binary representation of the "bin" number composed by "0" and "9" instead of "0" and "1".
While the "find" method is starting from 1 and checking if the number generated by "translate" is divisible by "divisible"