# Why replacing Objects (a class) with some arrays (primitive datatypes) in java reduce the run time significantly?

Tags: java, arrays, class, runtime

In my program I have a following class:

```
   private static class Node
   {
      // True if '1', false otherwise (i.e. '0')
      public final boolean isDigitOne;

      // The number represented in the tree modulo the input number
      public final int val;

      // The parent node in the tree
      public final Node parent;

      public Node(boolean isDigitOne, int val, Node parent)
      {
         this.isDigitOne = isDigitOne;
         this.val = val;
         this.parent = parent;
      }
   }
```

I replaced this class with two arrays of following inside a method of another class.

```
boolean[] product0 = new boolean[num]; 
int[] product1 = new int[num];
```

The rest of the program is very similar, the class implementation creates an object when needed where as the array implementation allocate the maximum needed memory at the beginning of the execution.

I measure the run time on both cases.

I noticed for smaller values of `num`, the execution time is almost same. But for larger value, the array implementation runs much quicker.

Here is the comparison:

[image]

My question is **Why array implementation runs faster?**

The class implementation is available in the following link as "Answer 3" 
[How to find the smallest number with just 0 and 1 which is divided by a given number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16458026/how-to-find-the-smallest-number-with-just-0-and-1-which-is-divided-by-a-given-nu)

Comment: You are comparing apples and oranges.  An array is a collection of items - your Node class is not.  What is the collection you are using to traverse the Nodes?  What operation(s) are you comparing in your timings?

Comment: What operation(s) are you actually doing? We have no idea what code is executing, therefore cannot speculate why there might be a performance difference.

Comment: I modified my question for full reference. @Dave Newton

Comment: When you using an Object, you have also a lot of object creations, mutch more memory operations etc, on the opposite using a primitive array is very simple to handle when it allocated/created once at start time

Comment: The time is the execution time for the full program for a single instance of num. I didn't want to repeat the full program here, I just add the link of the original class representation here. @Amir Afghani.

Answer (score 1):

A big part of it will be due to the location of data in memory. Arrays of objects don't directly store data next to each other in memory, instead it stores a reference to the location of where the data is stored in memory. This means that after accessing the array's location and grabbing the data from the array, the system then has to grab the data from the location in memory the value of the array is pointing to. Arrays of primitive data, however, have the data directly stored in the array. This means the system only has to do one look up to access the array instead of two to access the array and then access an object. Systems usually work so fast that it's not significantly noticeable for smaller amounts of data but it can become apparent when the amount of data is increased.

Comment: Can you tighten up the definition of "look around"? A reference is a reference. There *are* reasons a contiguous block *may* be faster than not--it might be good to include one or more of those reasons rather than hand-waving about "looking around" :/

Comment: @DaveNewton Will do. Been a few years since I've learned the specifics of how RAM stores arrays of objects vs how it stores arrays of actual data. Correct me if I'm wrong on this, but the biggest difference will be that for collections of objects the system will have to look up the object after grabbing the location from the array vs for an array of primitives the value is stored directly in the array?

Comment: Here I didn't use array of objects, rather than all the objects are forming a binary tree with a single father node. I just efficiently replace the tree structure by using two arrays. For lower values of num, class implementation took less time but for larger values of num, array implementation is faster. As I said, array implementation allocates the maximum needed memory at the beginning (that may not required all the time) but class implementation will allocate as needed.

Comment: @ManojBanik Hmm, fair enough. I can only speculate that it would have to do with the efficiency difference between running down a chain of references to find the next object vs running down an array to find the next reference. If the system has to keep looking from one reference to next to find the next object in a tree, then it will be less efficient than calculating an offset into an array to find the next reference.

Comment: That make sense, Okay, I will measure the time for different part of program to get a clear idea of which one causing delay. Thanks. @Tim Hunter

Answer (score 0):

Think of arrays as being like a linear organizer with boxes for all the data, with the array reference, you can just add the index to get to the relevant cube, and it directly contains the boolean or num value, so you can pull it out, do assignments and such very easily, since it's all right there.

This changes if you have an object, since that will be stored in a reference somewhere. That's like having an organizer with an address of another organizer somewhere else. So then you have to follow the address to do whatever you want to do. On top of that, once you get to that other organizer, it has to find the place where you wanted the data! This consumes more memory and more cycles as the memory grows.

TL;DR: arrays are faster because they take up a constant size and everything can be referenced explicitly by index. Objects are slower because they are typically stored as references to other places in memory and the offsets of class object must be computed implicitly by referencing the object property.